# SQL Datetime column represented incorrectly

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, parsing, sql-server-2019

When attempting to interact with column in a SQL Server table of type `DATETIME`, a certain row seems to parse incorrectly.

The `DATETIME` is initially represented in the format `dd:mm:yyyy hh:ss`, with the value parsing incorrectly being `12/6/2022 22:06`, when attempting to interact with this value in any way (`CAST`, `CONVERT`, etc) it will parse into some form of the date `'2022-12-07T03:06:00'`.

This is the only value (`'12/6/2022 22:06'`) out of 600 entries I can find parsing incorrectly.

I unfortunately only have read access to this database.

I have tried to force a conversion of this value into a text (`nvarchar`), or a different `DATE` format but the date gets parsed regardless for example:

```
CAST(dateoccurred AS varchar(19))
```

will become `'Dec 7 2022 3:06AM'`.

Is there a conversion function to force the value initially represented in query to a text format that I can parse later down the data pipeline?

The version used is Microsoft SQL Server 2019.

Comment: Datetime doesn't need parsing, it's a binary value. It has no format either, for the same reason. Neither do the other date and time related types. Are you confusing the way applications or client tools display the dates for an actual format? Or is the column a *text* column containing date strings in a certain format?

Comment: You'll have to post *executable* code that actually demonstrates the problem. Datetime is binary, that's not debatable. Nor can the field type change just for a single value. Something else is going on but we can't guess from the question

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Yes, perhaps I am, it is odd to me that all the other dates get represented correctly.

Comment: BTW, you should be using `datetime2` not `datetime`, as per Microsoft's official recommendation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql

Comment: Use `CONVERT` with the right `style` argument in order to get a specific format: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @Dai
 I unfortunately only have access to a SQL query editor the web app provides

Comment: Why do you care how the web app displays dates anyway? The *dates* don't have a format. I guess you can't modify the web app

Comment: If `22:06` is getting changed to `3:06` - I would suspect that the value is a `datetimeoffset` rather than `datetime`

Comment: That, or the *web app* performs an explicit timezone conversion. Perhaps there's a timezone setting in that web app that can be configured per user?

Comment: Is the *actual* string `2022-12-07T03:06:00` or *2022-12-07T03:06:00**Z***? The style 127 generates a UTC time with that format. `Z` stands for Zulu/UTC/00:00

Comment: I can check, I do believe it is an issue with the webapp, but they are notoriously hard to get a hold of and I was wondering if there is a way to force the value into its most basic form.

Comment: My apologies, `2022-12-07T03:06:00` is just how it gets represented later down the pipeline. All the other rows get represented as such (except correctly), I will edit my question.

Comment: If you can only modify the query you could try to reverse the change with `SWITCHOFFSET` or `AT TIME ZONE`, but that is very fragile. You'd have to keep changing the offsets to match DST changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that there was a discrepancy in the formats, the dates originally shown in the web app was of the format mm:dd:yyyy, but the dates pulled from the api were in yyyy:mm:dd, in conjunction with a time zone difference.

Answer (score 1):

To reliably convert datetime to text and back use ISO 8601 format, which is style 126 in [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
select convert(varchar(200), dateoccured, 126)
```

The text will look like

```
2023-07-14T14:25:50.250
```

Comment: I suspect someone used 127, generating a UTC time and omitted the `Z`, or the OP forgot to paste it